# Dual variable calculus

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

If $z=v'(w)$ and we introduce new variable $J(z)=v(w)-wz$. Then it is clear that $J'(z)=-w$ but why is $J''(z)=-1/v''(w)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Inverse Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)
$$ \frac{d}{dz} J'(z) = \frac{d}{dz} (-w) = -\frac{d}{dz} ((v')^{-1}(z)) = -\frac{1}{v''((v')^{-1}(z))} = -\frac{1}{v''(w)}$$
The exponent of $-1$ represents an inverse in the third part of the equation.

Comment: I don't understand your second equality. Maybe you made a mistake.

Comment: @Vaolter - Yes I did, thanks.